# How to move the text a bit up and to the right?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How it should be: http://prntscr.com/59nrxz

How it is: http://prntscr.com/59nsfg

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 logo" id="header-logo">
    <a href="{{ path('static_page', {template:'home'}) }}" title="Return Home">
        <img alt="logo" src="static/img/Risne-Logo.png"></img>
        <span class="logo_left">RISNE</span>
        <span class="logo_right">STARS</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.logo_left, .logo_right {
    font-family: "Droid Sans";
    font-size: 34px;
    top: -20px;
}
.logo_right {
    color: #FECD0F;
}
.logo_left {
   color: #234371;
}
```

I don't care about font or anything, i just need to get the text to move to the right position.

Comment: it would help if you also include the CSS you've already applied to this HTML so we can avoid causing problems with conflicting rules.

Comment: One is centered vertically, the other is just aligned with the top.  Maybe adjust the span, so it isnt inline, and then it might work.  Might need to adjust it slightly with like a vertical-align:top; or something

Comment: Also post CSS and full image link etc. Now we can't work with it.

Comment: padding: bottom 20px;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you want, a simple `position: relative` could do the trick.

```
.logo{
    position: relative;
    top: -20px; /* This will move it 20px up */
    left: 20px; /* This will move it 20px to the right */
}
```

That'a assuming that you put both of your `span`'s in a `div` (or heading) that has a class of `logo`.

Comment: changing the position type of the element is likely to cause problems with pre-existing CSS. i recommend not setting a position value and using margin-top and margin-left instead, and also using pre-existing elements rather than adding a wrapper div.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked :p       Need to wait 3 minutes before i can accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this it might do the trick :

```
.logo_left, .logo_right{
   vertical-align : top;
   margin-left : 10px; 
}
```