# How can I align text on top of a column in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my code and a screenshot of the website.
How can I align my text "button will show a page as below" on the left but on the same height like the start of my picture?

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="well">
          <h4>Item Price</h4>
          <span class="align-baseline";><img src="https://picsum.photos/200" class="img thumbnail" align="middle"/>
            button will show a page as below</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: My Screenshot]

I am talking about the first column!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got it:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="well">
          <h4>Item Price</h4>
          <div id="image" style="display:inline;">
           <img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/>
           </div>
           <div id="texts" class="logo"; style="display:inline whitespace:nowrap;">
               A very long text(about 300 words)
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

My css clas:

```
.logo{
    position: relative;
    top: -70px; /* This will move it 20px up */
    left: 20px; /* This will move it 20px to the right */
  }
```

Thanks to [Drown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3353357/drown) who answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108563/how-to-move-the-text-a-bit-up-and-to-the-right) question

Answer (score 0):

instead of making the logo position relative you can use

```
margin-top:-70px
margin-left:20px
```

absolute position for this task is not recommended.